# start at 9:00:30 and every 30s execute cron?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

Is there a way to set it to start at 9:00:30 every morning, execute it every 30 seconds until 9:30:00 ?

My expression is `30/30 0-30 9 ? * MON-SUN`, but it can't do what I want.

--edit--

It is now from 9:00 to 9:30 and the schedule will be executed in 30 seconds

```
9:00:30 executed 
9:01:30 executed 
9:02:30 executed 
9:03:30 executed 
9:04:30 executed
...
...
9:30:30 executed
```

---

the job I want

```
9:00:30 executed
9:01:00 executed
9:01:30 executed
9:02:00 executed
9:02:30 executed
9:03:00 executed
9:03:30 executed
...
...
9:30:00 executed
```

Please Help

Comment: "it can't do what I want" isn't going to help much - you might want to provide some details, e.g. what happens instead. The expression already seems to be on a good way - I'd just have 2 observations: 1) instead of `MON-SUN` why not just `*` as it covers every day of the week? (and it might have to be `SUN-MON` in any case) 2) you seem to have forgotten to mention the year in the end - not sure if the scheduler is lenient enough to accept it that way.

Comment: Finally, if the expression doesn't work you might want to share some more details on how you're using it and what you tried to confirm that other expressions work.

Comment: More details are required, what is the current behavior, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: Updated my question and added working status now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two cron expressions to achieve what you want:

1. `30 0-29 9 * * ?`

Executes every minute from 09:00:30 to 09:29:30

```
Output

09:00:30
09:01:30
09:02:30
09:03:30
09:04:30
...
09:29:30
```

2. `0 1-30 9 * * ?`

Executes every minute from 09:01:00 to 09:30:00

```
Output

09:01:00
09:02:00
09:03:00
09:04:00
09:05:00
...
09:30:00
```